# Put words in a string array

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
public static String[] wordList(String line){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
    String[] words = line.split(" ");
    for( int i=0; i<words.length; i++)
    {
        String word = scanner.next();
        return words[i] = word;
    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

On the line `return words[i] = word;` I get the error message saying "cannot convert String to String[]". Help?

Answer (score 2):

`line.split()` *already* gives you an array, you just need to return that:

```
public class Test {
    public static String[] wordList(String line){
        return line.split(" ");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {    
        String xyzzy = "paxdiablo has left the building";
        String[] arr = wordList(xyzzy);
        for (String s: arr)
            System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Running that gives:

```
paxdiablo
has
left
the
building
```

Keep in mind that's for *one space* between each word. If you want a more general solution that uses a separator of "any amount of whitespace", you can use this instead:

```
public static String[] wordList(String line){
    return line.split("\\s+");
}
```

The regular expressions that you can use with `String.split()` can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum).

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] words = line.split(" ");
```

Is all you need. The split() method already returns an array of Strings.

Comment: @Dando18 Wrong. `" "` is also a valid regex. And btw `\s` is not whitespace only.

Comment: @m0skit0 just looked it up and you're right. All these years I thought you had to use `\s`. Thanks

Comment: @m0skit0, I'm confused, how exactly is `\s` not whitespace only? It's _defined_ as `\s - a whitespace character: [<space>\t\n\x0B\f\r]` as per http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum. If you mean "not space only", I can understand that.

Comment: @paxdiablo that would include tabs, right? not just space

Comment: @Dando18, yes, spaces, horizontal-tabs, newlines, vertical-tabs, form-feeds, carriage-returns.

Comment: Yeah, I meant space character, english is not my native language, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to split by spaces, you're method should look like:

```
public static String[] wordList(String line){
    return line.split(" ");
}
```

Comment: Dat won't compile in Java bro

Comment: @m0skit0, I applaud your efforts to assist the answerer but maybe you could have gone the extra step and explained _why._ In this case, it's simply that you have to escape the backslash within the string.

Comment: @paxdiablo It's simple and he would notice if he compiles it :) I'm also sure he already knows the correct syntax from other comments he made.

Comment: Dando, your change to use a space in your code rather than `\s` means that your text is now mismatched. You should change "whitespaces" into "a space", or something like that.